# error when creating a partitioned table

Tags: hive, partition

I am new to Hive and got an error when I tried to create a partitioned table.

here is my script:

```
CREATE　TABLE partitionedemp(emp_no int, birth_date string, first_name string, last_name string) Partitioned By(gender string, hire_date string) stored as sequencefile;
```

I got an error below:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

What's wrong with my script? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is fine , Just you have ^M characters between CREATE and TABLE keywords. To check, paste this command in vi editor and run command like this:-

```
$ cat -v file.txt
CREATEM-cM-^@M-^@TABLE partitionedemp(emp_no int, birth_date string, first_name string, last_name string) Partitioned By(gender string, hire_date string) stored as sequencefile;
```

Solution:- Straightforward one - type full create table statement on hive prompt instead of copy and paste.

Comment: Thank you, just be curious, how do you find out the invisible ^M ?

Comment: Just little debugging and little bit knowledge on unix :)